# Using multiple layouts with include tag in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to create a title bar that is the same throughout my application and have been creating layouts like this for each of my activities:

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <include layout="@layout/title_bar_layout" android:id="@+id/title_bar_layout" />
 <include layout="@layout/main_body" android:id="@+id/main_body" />
</LinearLayout>
```

main_body.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/main_table" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:stretchColumns="1"
 android:orientation="vertical">
</TableLayout>
```

my onCreate contains:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
TableLayout t = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_table);
```

but t always ends up null.

Comment: In your example the main layout file is called 'main' but you setContentView with 'schedule'. Is there a link ? If not, check whether there is no other id/main_table element in the same layout.

Comment: Actually was just a typo in my question, sorry! Edited it to reflect what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
TableLayout t = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_body);
```

From this [page](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html):

> you can use android:id to specify the
>   id of the root view of the included
>   layout; it will also override the id
>   of the included layout if one is
>   defined